# Seralize a string and save it into a MySQL database in Java

Tags: java, mysql, serialization

In my project I have to save a huge string in a MySQL column. The string represents XML data and if you save it to a file it will have 5mb.

I created a table for that with the column datatype as `TEXT`. But I heard that saving very large strings in a database is not recommended, so I decided to use serialization.

I want to serialize the string and save it in the column, so I changed the column datatype as `blob` in order to save it but first I have to serialize the string.

I came to this method using a Google search

```
String hugeText = "this is very big text";  
saveInTable(hugeText .getBytes());
```

The above method `saveInTable` saves the infomation in the database. I see the column data `0x......etc`.

Is this the correct way to serialize it?

Comment: you can put it in object class who implements serializable

Comment: @alias_boubou  String class implements Serializable, so i did like this

Comment: try CLOB you will need no conversion to byte[]

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev if we use clob can we directly use saveInTable(hugeText );  ??